# Why does a string get mutilated when it becomes `this`?

Tags: javascript

I discovered a peculiarity in JavaScript (or perhaps my browser's idea of it):

```
var s = "Hello, world";

function foo(arg)
{
    console.log(arg);
    console.log(this);
}

foo.call(s, s);
```

Running the above with Firebug console enabled, I get:

```
Hello, world
String { 0="H", 1="e", more...}
```

Why does the string automatically get turned into a weird object before becoming the `this` passed to `foo` ?

The reason I call it a weird object is because jQuery chokes on it.  For example:

```
$.each(["one", "two", "three"], function(i, x) {
    $('<p></p>').text(x)   .appendTo('body'); // Works
    $('<p></p>').text(this).appendTo('body'); // Doesn't work
});
```

Comment: Well, `this` should refer to the `window`, if it's not within a function.

Comment: Interesting behavior, assuming related to passing the incorrect number of arguments. I use the arguments object if there's a variable number of args.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is coerced into an object, i.e. `Object("test")` is internally called.

```
(function() {
    return this;
}).call("test");

// returns same as `new String("test")` or `Object("test")`
```

> [if the method is a function in non-strict mode ... primitive values will be boxed*.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call)

Note that using strict mode indeed does return the primitive value:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    return this;
}).call("test") === "test"; // true
```

---

> * [Boxing a value of a value allocates an object instance and copies the value into the new object.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25z57t8s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Because `this` is just an object (I know strings are objects, but they are also strings):

```
var s = "Hello, world";

function foo(arg)
{
    console.log(typeof arg); // string
    console.log(typeof this); // object
}

foo.call(s, s);
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `foo.call(s1, s2)`, you're invoking function `foo`, and setting the `this` keyword to `s1`. Since `this` has to be an object (so, not a primitive value), it's converted to a `String` object.

The individual characters of a string (created through `s = "..."` or `s = String("...")`) can be accessed through indexes, hence

```
String { 0="H", 1="e", more...}
```

---

```
function foo(arg)
{
    console.log(arg);   // passed as "Hello, world"
    console.log(this);  // passed as String("Hello, world")
    console.log(this instanceof String); //True
}
```

---

Code to demonstrate the indexes:

```
var i=0, s = "Hello, world";
for(; i<s.length; i++){
    console.log(i, s[i]);
}
/* Prints:
   0 H
   1 e
    ...
  */
 */
```